# How do you compare all fields in multiple feature classes?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, comparison

I have two features classes that should have the exact same fields. There are over 500 fields, I am looking for a code that will compare the fields and identify if there are fields in either feature class that are not in the other.
I found this solution, [Comparing multiple field values of two feature classes using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290684/comparing-multiple-field-values-of-two-feature-classes-using-arcpy) but was hoping to not have to type out each field.

Comment: Do the rows within the fields need to be the same? Have you tried using `ListFields` and comparing the lists? More details: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm

Comment: Yes I have used ListFields but I was hoping to find something that loops through the feature classes and identifies difference in the 2 features classes.

Comment: Dow the values contained within the fields need to be the same too, or just the field names?

Comment: There are no values in the fields, they are blank.

Comment: Finally, do the field types have to be the same between the two?

Comment: Yes the fields types, names and lengths need to be the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

List the fields using set comprehension, compare the sets:

```
import arcpy

fc1 = r'C:\GIS\data\Bakgrundskartor_LMV\Oversiktskartan.gdb\ak_riks'
fc2 = r'C:\GIS\data\Bakgrundskartor_LMV\Oversiktskartan.gdb\ak_riks_1'

fields1 = {f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc1)}
fields2 = {f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc2)}

print 'Fields in common: ', fields1.intersection(fields2)

if not fields1==fields2: #If they are not the same
    print 'only exist in fc1, and not in fc2: ', fields1.difference(fields2)
    print 'only exist in fc2, and not in fc1: ', fields2.difference(fields1)
```

[image]

Comment: I see you are using set() methods but is fields1 and fields2 not a dictionary because  they are {}?

Comment: No sets also use {}. I guess python know it is a set if there are no key:values

Comment: Ah OK! I've only ever created a set like `mySet = set()` never knew it could be {}, I find that confusing! But a good answer showing the power of sets.

Comment: Nice, clean approach to check if the field names and list sizes are the same. The OP is also looking to check if the fields are the same type. How about integrating a check using `f.type`?